# Is it alright to define a helping Class in a python test module?

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a python module pikachu.py. For testing pikachu.py, I have test_pikachu.py. In test_pikachu.py, I have the test class TestPikachu (unittest.TestCase).

Now to test a requirement for pikachu.py, I need to start a thread. So, I would like to define another class - class HelperThread - inside the test_pikachu.py. Is this then still a clean pythonic way?

Or should I define the HelperThread class in an another module?

Comment: As long as this `HelperThread` is used in `test_pikachy.py` only then this is absolutely fine. Although I'd rather pass a function to `Thread` constructor instead of inheriting from `Thread` (if that's what you mean).

Answer (score 1):

I can highly recommend the book [Building Skills in Object-Oriented Design](http://buildingskills.itmaybeahack.com/book/oodesign-3.1/latex/BuildingSkillsinObject-OrientedDesign.pdf)

It has a test case where you need to test a roulette player who bets randomly. Obviously testing random is not possible so a new class is introduced in the test to simulate a random roll but returning always the same value.
Have a look at my [code](https://github.com/analphagamma/RouletteGame/blob/master/tests/randomplayertest.py)